# Copy the first n files from one directory to another

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, copy-paste

Im looking to copy the first 'n' files from one directory to another directory preferably with only cli tools (no scripts).

I've tried the following:

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -5 | xargs cp -t /target/directory`

  > This looked promising, but failed because osx `cp` command doesn't appear to have the
  >   `-t` switch
- `exec` in a few different configurations

  > This probably failed for syntax problems on my end : /
  >   I couldn't seem to get a `head` type selection working

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `-J` option with `xargs`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n5 | xargs -J X cp X /target/directory
```

The `J` option places all the filenames into the placeholder X, which can be any character(s) and `cp` accepts multiple files to a target directory. It can be visualized as-

```
cp file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 DESTINATION
```

EDIT:

To handle filenames with spaces, we have `tr` translate the newline character to the null character after each filename and then have xargs handle the null bit as a separator for the filenames.

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n5 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -J X cp -- X /target/directory
```

Comment: Excellent solution, just what I was after! Could you explain the 'n' in `head -n5`?  At any rate, big thanks, and thanks @user3439894 for your input as well!

Comment: @visyoual - From the manual: ` head [-n count | -c bytes] [file ...]`

Comment: Ok. In my search for other solutions prior to posting this questions, several had the head command with `-5` and not `-n5`. Wasn't sure if that was acceptable shorthand, or syntax error. I guess i'm still not sure.

Comment: As you mentioned to me in a comment to my answer, your solution does not handle filenames with spaces, it there a way to achieve it modifying your command slightly?

Comment: @visyoual, JSYK If your filenames contain spaces, fd0's solution doesn't work with filenames containing spaces and you can use the one in my answer, which fd0 improved, until he updates his answer.

Comment: @visyoual - depends on the version of head that you are using, With GNU head `-n5` would mean the first five lines and `-5` would mean all but the last five lines. With BSD head both are the same.

Comment: @fd0 Thank you for the clarification. At the risk of pressing my luck here = ] would a solution that handles spaces in filenames be markedly different, or would using @user3439894’s answer be the next best thing? (Purely academic)

Comment: @visyoual,  fd0 updated his answer, I would use his updated answer over mine.

Comment: @fd0, why don't you just use the updated command and remove the one that doesn't handle spaces? Is then a reason to have both versions from an applied usage standpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I found a different solution without `xargs` or `-exec` but I think fd0's answer is a better way to go:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do cp "$f" "/target/directory/"; done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n5)
```

Comment: I'll suggest the you set `IFS` to nothing-`IFS=` to handle any leading or trailing spaces in a filename and use process substitution instead of command substitution and a here string. Your solution will definitely be slower but it will handle filenames with spaces in them. My solution will not in its current form.

Comment: @fd0, Good suggestion. I know with `IFS=` it would be `IFS=; while read ...` but not sure how to swap out the _command substitution_ and _here string_ for _process substitution_ instead, without doing some research. Would not mind you showing me or even editing my answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @fd0, I missed the extra `<` in `... done < <( ...` in my testing. :)